# Is there a way to make a function wait for image to show up then clicking the image while on display using PyAutoGui (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently making a BTD6 Auto Farmer what this means is that it will farm the game for me and click on the screen and play the game for me and complete the maps and stuff so I can get rewards that do not give me a competitive advantage because the game is single-player.

And to complete this bot I'd have to wait a certain amount of time and then see whenever a button shows up on the screen and to accomplish this I need to make a function that will wait for an image to show up on the screen and if the image shows up the function should press that image and that's all.

I tried many things and couldn't get it to work, here is my code that doesn't work:

```
def click_image(img):
    x = pag.locateCenterOnScreen(img, confidence=config.OPENCV_CONFIDENCE)
    pag.click(x)
```

This didn't work and I'm not surprised because the code creates the variable then tries pressing the variable there is no check or wait and I don't know how to implement that and that's what I'm asking for, that's the answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: To get an answer, you should to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with OpenCV. It seems like pyautogui would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to perform an asynchronous task, you should look into the python package asyncio.